# UITableView, strange number of subviews in only one cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've a normal table with some customization in cells, a textview, a textfield, a button and a label. Here the code:

**header:**

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

@interface ALCViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *prodottiArray;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *prodotti;

@end
```

**implementation:**

```
@implementation ALCViewController

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [prodottiArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];

        UITextView *productname = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 5, 100, 105)];
        [cell addSubview:productname];
        [productname setTag:1];/**/

        UILabel *price = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 5, 85, 26)];
        [cell addSubview:price];
        [price setTag:2];

        UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(235, 40, 45, 56)];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 56)];
        [buttonView addSubview:button];
        [cell addSubview:buttonView];
        [buttonView setTag:3];

        UIView *textfieldView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(235, 110, 45, 30)];
        UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 30)];
        [textfield setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [textfield setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
        [textfield setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [textfieldView addSubview:textfield];
        [cell addSubview:textfieldView];
        [textfieldView setTag:4];
    }

    NSDictionary *elemento = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[prodottiArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [(UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:1] setText:[elemento objectForKey:@"product_name"]];
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2] setText:[elemento objectForKey:@"price"]];
    [[[(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:3] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTag:[indexPath item]];

    NSLog(@"[(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:4] subviews] %d",[[(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:4] subviews] count]);

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

#pragma mark - INIT

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    #pragma mark - inizializzazione prodotti

    prodottiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        [prodottiArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"12",@"price",@"This is a name",@"product_name", nil]];
    }

    #pragma mark - Costruzione tabella

    self.prodotti = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-30) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.prodotti setDelegate:self];
    [self.prodotti setDataSource:self];
    [self.prodotti setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.prodotti setHidden:NO];
    [self.prodotti setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]];
    [self.prodotti setTag:0];

    [self.prodotti setRowHeight:150];
    [self.prodotti setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.prodotti];
    #pragma mark
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

I'v put button and textfield into a `UIView` because i need to give to this elements another tag.

That's the log taken in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. The view tagged with 4 have always 1 subview, but in the fifth row has 3 subviews!!! Why???

**the Log:**

```
2013-10-23 11:23:27.660 tableTest[2703:c07] [(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:4] subviews] 1
2013-10-23 11:23:29.478 tableTest[2703:c07] [(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:4] subviews] 3
2013-10-23 11:23:31.814 tableTest[2703:c07] [(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:4] subviews] 1
2013-10-23 11:23:33.415 tableTest[2703:c07] [(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:4] subviews] 1
2013-10-23 11:23:34.148 tableTest[2703:c07] [(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:4] subviews] 1
2013-10-23 11:23:36.651 tableTest[2703:c07] [(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:4] subviews] 1
```

I'm using Xcode5 and it happens both in simulator (ios7, ios6.1) and device (ios6.1)

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

As suggested i tried to add views to cell.contentView instead directly in cell, but without changes in log

Comment: Try adding those views (the text field, label and button view) to the cell's `contentView` instead of directly on to it. Does that make a difference? `UITableView`s actually have a lot of magic going on under the hood, so it's hard to understand the introspection results.

Comment: Thankyou Guy Kogus but no results :(

Comment: Maybe you should try tags over 1000+ because some tags are reserved for the system use ...

Comment: D33pN16h7 you save me! Put your hint into an answer and i'll accept!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same situation.But I have a solution for it. I just changed a tags over 1000+ and it works perfect for me. When I searched for this then I got 1 reason and the reason is some tags are already reserver for system use.May it helps you.Try it.

Comment: :) I just shared my experience.